# Split function in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am little bit confuse in Split function in Vb.Net.

```
If hdnDetails.Value.Split("|").Length = 0 Then
         lblMsg.Text="Error"
End If
```

This statement is always true even `hdnDetails.Value=""`. Split function returning length 1 always. What is the solution to get 0 length?

Comment: The solution is an empty string! Edit: Sorry, empty string returns 1, too. I am not sure if there is any constellation where the returned array will be 0.

Comment: There are no solutions. You need to check for length 1 which means that the input text was not split.

Comment: This code is [tag:vb.net] please do not use unnecessary tags such as [tag:c#].

Comment: Solution is to not use `Split`. If you want to check whether the string *contains* any pipe characters, there's a simple method available that explicitly identifies itself as performing that check.

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve the length 0? you want to handle if the string doesn't contain "|"?

Comment: If you split with an character that is not present in the input string the length will always be 1 (containing the input string). This is default .NET behavior. Either you check for Length > 1 or you use Contains: `hdnDetauls.Value.Contains("|")`

Comment: `If Not hdnDetails.Value.Contains("|") Then ...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes can check pipe character. But i was trying to get solution in split function.

Comment: @SAL: if the array-length is 1 you know there was no pipe

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok got it. Its mean Split function will not return 0 at any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) will never return an array with `Length = 0` (with this overload). MSDN:

> If this instance does not contain any of the characters in separator,
>   the returned array consists of a single element that contains this
>   instance.

So you should use `String.Contains` if you want to check if the string contains a char:

```
If Not hdnDetails.Value.Contains("|") Then
    lblMsg.Text="Error"
Else
    Dim array = hdnDetails.Value.Split("|")
    ' Do something with this array if you need it
End If
```

You should note that checking if the array length is 1 can also be wrong if you want to know whether the string contained the separator or not. The array length can even be 0 if you use the [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a `StringSplitOptions` argument.

Consider the string contains only the separator so it's `"|"` and you pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, then the **resulting array will have a length of 0**.

If you pass `StringSplitOptions.None` you will get an array with length of 2: **two empty strings**.